# Возможность сохранения сессии между доменом и поддоменами

Tags: php, сессия

Вот такой вопрос организовался - возможность сохранения сессии между доменом и поддоменами.

Пока склоняюсь только к одному варианту - сохранять  данные сессий в куках и на поддоменах уже проверять, что там да как.

Но вот хотелось бы узнать, может быть, есть еще какие варианты? Более удобные, без ковыряния куков и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ставить куку нужно на домен типа: .site.com

То есть с точкой перед доменом второго уровня. После чего в поддоменной зоне эта кука будет доступна.

Comment: <?php
 
    $currentCookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); 
    
    $rootDomain = '.example.com'; 
    
    session_set_cookie_params( 
        $currentCookieParams["lifetime"], 
        $currentCookieParams["path"], 
        $rootDomain, 
        $currentCookieParams["secure"], 
        $currentCookieParams["httponly"] 
    ); 

    session_name('mysessionname'); 
    session_start(); 

    setcookie($cookieName, $cookieValue, time() + 3600, '/', $rootDomain); 
    ?>